# Looking for an equivalent to Math Stack Exchange for a Korean mathematician.

Tags: reference-request

I have a Korean friend whose English is passable for conversation, but not great. She's having a hard time with statistics, and her English comprehension is not good enough to use Khan Academy, Stack Exchange, and similar English sites (and unfortunately KA doesn't offer lessons in Korean). I was hoping to recommend a site that can help with math problems but for Korean speakers. Unfortunately I can't speak or read a bit of Korean and have no idea where I would start looking. Can any of the illustrious mathematicians here recommend a sort of tutorial/tutoring site similar to this one but for a Korean speaker?

Comment: It should be fine to post questions in Korean here, add a rough automatic translation, and people here can help correcting it. Answers will probably come in English.

Comment: The problem is her English reading comprehension is only passable. I'd like to recommend a site that will give answers in Korean